# Scheduled jobs never run when created in managed package

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-apex

I am implementing the InstallHandler interface for a managed package which creates a scheduled job to run.  A scheduled job is created when I install the package, with a status of Queued.  However, the job never seems to run.

However, if I run the exact System.schedule command via anonymous Apex, the job actually gets created and runs properly.  This makes me believe that the job creation and underlying code are working properly, but perhaps there is a permissions issue preventing the job from running.  So far the only difference I can see is that the user is different for the two methods of creating the job.  When installed by the managed package, the Submitted By name is the name of my package, but when I run via anonymous Apex the Submitted By name is my SysAdmin user.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the actual job never runs?

Comment: Has the installed package been copied down to a Sandbox by any chance?

Comment: Nope.  I'm testing in a developer org, but not a sandbox.

Comment: Can you annotate `without sharing` on the InstallHandler and the Schedulable implementors, and then maybe confirm that the calculated start time is unaffected by user Locale settings?

Comment: Yep, this fixed it!  I thought simply not having "with sharing" would cover it, but I was wrong.  Thanks so much for the help @bigassforce!

Comment: @bigassforce Can you post an official answer for this? Sounds like it was the `without sharing` setting

Answer (score 1):

The runtime privileges of the class may be ambiguous.

If you annotate `without sharing` on the InstallHandler and the Schedulable implementors, that would eliminate one source of possible problems.

After that, it would be a great post-mortem followup to find out which particular part of the install handler or scheduled job happened to be very sensitive to sharing.